# Trouble fitting curve to data set

Tags: r, math, regression

For the last two days I've been trying to fit a curve to the following data set. As you can see (from the image) the data forms a near perfect curve on its own but I haven't been able to find a way to mathematically represent the data for both interpolation and extrapolation.

```
y = c(0.2966, 0.2793, 0.2147, 0.1523, 0.1177, 0.1026, 0.0934, 0.0767, 
 0.0729, 0.0693, 0.0658, 0.0624, 0.0561, 0.0502, 0.0424, 0.04, 0.0356, 
 0.0335, 0.0316, 0.0279, 0.0231, 0.0217, 0.0203, 0.019, 0.02, 0.016, 
 0.0151, 0.0134, 0.0127, 0.0119, 0.0113, 0.0106, 0.01, 0.0094, 0.0089,
  0.0084, 0.0074, 0.007, 0.0062, 0.0059, 0.0053, 0.0048, 0.0043, 
  0.0041, 0.0037, 0.0033, 0.0032, 0.003, 0.0029, 0.0025, 0.0024, 
  0.0023, 0.0021, 0.002, 0.0016, 0.0016, 0.0014, 0.0012, 0.001, 
  0.0007, 0.0006, 0.0004, 0.0003)

x = c(0.77894, 0.79452, 0.85683, 0.92694, 0.97367, 0.99704, 1.01262, 
   1.04378, 1.05157, 1.05936, 1.06714, 1.07493, 1.09051, 1.10609, 
    1.12946, 1.13725, 1.15283, 1.16062, 1.16841, 1.18399, 1.20735, 
    1.21514, 1.22293, 1.23072, 1.2463, 1.25409, 1.26188, 1.27746, 
    1.28525, 1.29304, 1.30083, 1.30862, 1.3164, 1.32419, 1.33198, 
    1.33977, 1.35535, 1.36314, 1.37872, 1.38651, 1.40209, 1.41767, 
    1.43325, 1.44103, 1.45661, 1.47219, 1.47998, 1.48777, 1.49556, 
    1.51893, 1.52672, 1.53451, 1.55009, 1.55788, 1.58903, 1.59682, 
    1.6124, 1.63577, 1.67472, 1.75261, 1.79156, 1.86945, 1.92398)
```

Here's is the data plotted with a exponential curve (pink) and a 4th order polynomial (red). The exponential curve has quite a bit of error while the 4th order fits but you can't extrapolate using it and when applying to similar data sets it doesn't always work.

For what I'm working on I really need something perfectly fits to the curve put I haven't figured out how to do it yet. Thanks.

[image]

Comment: You can try: `lm(log(y)~x)`

Comment: If I'm not mistaken isn't that the log transform for a exponential curve?

Comment: Looking at a plot of `log(y)` vs `x`, I would be extremely skeptical of any model more complicated than the exponential / `log(y) ~ x`.

Comment: Speculation about the close vote: Asking for a method that fits exactly and can be used for extrapolation is really demanding the impossible.

Comment: Thank you for providing your data in a format that is easily imported.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An object lesson in the perils of extrapolation.

In the absence of a theoretical model, your data is fit about equally well using either a logistic function (`f1(...)`) or a scaled log-normal density function (`f2(...)`). There are probably other functions that would also fit well.

```
df <- data.frame(x,y)
library(minpack.lm)   # for nlsLM(...)

f1 <- function(x,a,b,c,d) a*exp(-(b*x))/(1+c*exp(-d*x))
fit.1 <- nlsLM(y~f1(x,a,b,c,d), df, 
               start=c(a=1, b=1, c=100, d=0), control=list(maxiter=500))
f2 <- function(x,a,m,s) a*dlnorm(x, meanlog=m, sdlog=s)
fit.2 <- nlsLM(y~f2(x,a,m,s), df, 
               start=c(a=1, m=0, s=1), control=list(maxiter=500))

plot(y~x,df)
curve(predict(fit.1,data.frame(x)),add=TRUE, col="blue")
curve(predict(fit.2,data.frame(x)),add=TRUE, col="red")
```

[image]

But look what happens when you extrapolate.

```
plot(y~x, df, xlim=c(0.5,2), ylim=c(0,.6))
curve(predict(fit.1,data.frame(x)),add=TRUE, col="blue")
curve(predict(fit.2,data.frame(x)),add=TRUE, col="red")
```

[image]

It turns out that actually the log-normal density function is a slightly better fit in that the residuals are more nearly normal, although there is a strong pattern in the residuals in both cases. The point is that just by looking at the data and the fitted curve you might accept either function, but they will give very different results on extrapolation, and in fact neither one is a great fit. You really need a theoretical model.

Answer (score 2):

A LOESS regression seems to work quite well with that data.

```
plot(y~x)

ls <- loess(y~x, span = 0.5)
pr <- predict(ls, x)

lines(x, pr, col = "red", lwd = 2)
```

[image: LOESS regression]

Comment: that's a perfect fit, but there doesn't seem to be a way to get the mathematically representation from a loess function.

Comment: Is there any specific reason you need a mathematical representation? Unless you have a specific idea of the process underlying the generation of that data, I am not too sure what that would add. You can in any case use the predict function for interpolation.

Comment: This curve is part of a larger problem. I need this representation to solve that problem. Since it's one of the key relationships in the data. thanks.

Comment: Well, the good thing about using LOESS is that it is non parametric. Not saying that it is the solution to the world's problem, but if you don't have a theoretical model behind your data then it is probably a safer approach, having the advantage of not relying on a specific function to fit the data. You can still do interpolation/extrapolation, however, if you do need an equation then it's not a good solution (but see @jlhoward answer, which shows really well why assuming one specific equation without having a reason to is bad).

Answer (score 1):

Looks like 4th-order B-splines do pretty well:

```
library("splines")
m0 <- lm(y~bs(x,degree=4)) ## default: 5 df
m1 <- lm(y~bs(x,degree=4,df=6))
e1 <- glm(y~x,family=gaussian(link="log"))

par(las=1,bty="l")
plot(x,y,log="y")
lines(x,predict(m0))
lines(x,predict(m1),col=2)
lines(x,predict(e1,type="response"),col=4)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

A bilogarithmic plot tends to show a linear behavior (i.e. power law) for the large values, which later blends to a steeper slope. It seems that you might model this plot as a straight line plus an exponential, but extrapolation on the right is unsure.

[image]

This model is

```
log(y) = a.log(x) + b - c.d^log(x)
```

or

```
y = A.x^B.exp(-C.x^D)
```